# Source for Kiruv?

Tags: kiruv-outreach

I’ve heard that one who performs the Mitzvah of Kiruv, or bringing Hashem’s children back to him, has a special place in the world to come. What is the source for this and what does it say? Also I believe I’ve heard this this is the biggest Mitzvah in the Torah. What is the source for this as well? Thanks!